# style of lineHeight very unusual in ReactNative

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

when I use the LineHeight ,the font position of Text should Vertical center usually, but,the font show at the bottom of the alignment.

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <Text style={styles.welcome}>
       Welcome to React Native!
     </Text>
    </View>

    container: {
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
     backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
      fontSize: 20,
      textAlign: 'center',
      margin: 10,
      height: 60,
   // lineHeight: 60,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    }
```

I don't know what caused this,anyone can give me some suggestions?thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which platform you are in and with React Native version you are running.

However, this issue was addressed for Android platform with React Native <= 0.51.

So, if your environment is the same => update to React Native 0.52 or above to solve that.